# How can I make the robe act like a robe?

Tags: rigging, weight-painting

So I'm Making a robe for a character pose that involves a robe. From the angle in the image, the robe somewhat looks okay. [image]

But when you look at it from the other side, it tells a different story.
[image]

I've tried weight painting the robe to the specified legs, but every time I try, It just drags more than I wanted.

Here's the file to the model.
[image]

Comment: It depends on how close to reality you want the robe to behave.  If you want a reasonable approximation, you're going to have to give the robe is own bones and animate them because robes flow according to both your movement and cloth physics.

Comment: as Marty says you can give it bones, or you can give it cloth physics but it will be a bit more complicated to set

Comment: Thank you. I think I got the robe to work